# can I achieve directive composition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have multiple directives with templates and transclusion enabled. I add these directives to an element as attributes, and I want the resulting markup to be generated by applying the templates one after the other, in am manner similar to function composition. Is this possible at all with non-nested directives?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want by specifying a priority for your directives to control the order in which they are applied.